# AttributeError (Python)

Tags: python, tags, mp3

I'm changing tags in multiple .mp3 files. I'm using eyed3.

```
audio = eyed3.load(f'C:\\Users\\axeld\\Desktop\\Music\\NG Test\\{item}')
audio.tag.artist = Author_name
audio.tag.title = Song_name.replace(".mp3", "")
audio.tag.save()
```

It works perfectly through some files, but suddenly I get this error:

```
audio.tag.artist = Author_name
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'artist'
```

Why does it work with some files and with others not if they all have the same tags?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't accidentally grab some non-audio files (I assume you run this in a loop)? Or audio files for which `.tag` cannot be loaded or whatever and returns None

Comment: @PeterWood `audio` itself isn't `None` here. It's `audio.tag` that is `None`.

Comment: @h4z3 It is in a loop. When I run a loop to print all the items in the folder, it prints all .mp3 files and two .jpg files (AlbumArtSmall.jpg and Folder.jpg). When I search for these two files on the File Explorer it says that they don't exist. So, where am I getting those files form?

Comment: you could display file name before you get `tag.artist` to see which file makes problem.

Comment: See how to create a [mcve]. At the moment you're asking us to debug a problem on your machine. We need to be able to reproduce the problem for ourselves to troubleshoot it. By creating the minimal example, you might spot your error.

Comment: @furas `if not audio.tag: print(filepath)`

Comment: I would simply use `print(filepath)` or maybe `print(item)` - even without any `if`. But before link which makes problem.

Comment: I get the error with multiple .mp3 files. The jpg files have nothing to do with it

Comment: Edit the question.